# CMD with pipe in Dockerfile doesn't forward

Tags: node.js, docker

I have this command to start a Node.js webserver like this:

```sh
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --preserve-symlinks /app/api/dist/server.js | pino-pretty
```

I'm placing it into a Dockerfile as the `CMD`:

```
CMD ["node", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229", "--preserve-symlinks" ,"/app/api/dist/server.js", "|","pino-pretty"]
```

The service starts when calling `docker run`  but the `|` is ignored so no logs are forwarded to `pino-pretty`.

What am I doing wrong here?

I could put the whole command into a `start.sh` or use `CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]` but I want to understand the core problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could put the whole command into a start.sh or use CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"] but I want to understand the core problem.

A pipe is a shell construct, e.g. a feature of `/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash`, and similar shells. When you define CMD with the json/exec syntax, you are explicitly telling docker to run the command without a shell. Therefore you need to either run the command in a script, call a shell explicitly, or run with the string/shell syntax to have docker execute the command with a shell:

```
CMD node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --preserve-symlinks /app/api/dist/server.js | pino-pretty
```